# Subset data with dynamic conditions in R

Tags: r, optimization, subset

I have a dataset of 2500 rows which are all bank loans. Each bank loan has an outstanding amount and collateral type. (Real estate, Machine tools.. etc)

I need to draw a random selection out of this dataset where for example the sum of outstanding amount = 2.5Million +-5% and maximum 25% loans with the same asset class.

I found the function optim, but this asks for a function and looks to be constructed for optimization a portfolio of stocks, which is much more complex. I would say that there is an easy way of achieving this?

I created a sample data set which could illustrate my question better:

```
dataset <- data.frame(balance=c(25000,50000,35000,40000,65000,10000,5000,2000,2500,5000)
                      ,Collateral=c("Real estate","Aeroplanes","Machine tools","Auto Vehicles","Real estate",
                                    "Machine tools","Office equipment","Machine tools","Real estate","Auto Vehicles"))
```

If I want for example 5 loans out of this dataset which sum of outstanding balance = 200.000 (with 10% margin) and not more than 40% is allowed to be the same collateral type. (so maximum 2 out of 5 in this example)

Please let me know if additional information is necessary.
Many thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function I made works:

```
pick_records <- function(df,size,bal,collat,max.it) {
  i <- 1
  j <- 1
  while ( i == 1 ) {
    s_index <- sample(1:nrow(df) , size)
    print(s_index)
    output <- df[s_index,]
    out_num <- lapply(output,as.numeric)
    tot.col <- sum(as.numeric(out_num$Collateral))
    if (sum(out_num$balance) < (bal*1.1) &
          sum(out_num$balance) > (bal*0.9) &
          all(  table(out_num$Collateral)/size  <= collat)   ) {
      return(output)
      break
    }
    print(j)
    j <- j + 1
    if ( j == max.it+1) {
      print('No solution found')
      break}     
  }
} 

> a <- pick_records(dataset,5,200000,0.4,20)
> a
  balance       Collateral
3   35000    Machine tools
7    5000 Office equipment
4   40000    Auto Vehicles
5   65000      Real estate
2   50000       Aeroplanes
```

Where `df` is your dataframe, `size` is the number of records you want and `max.it` the number of maximum iterations to find a solution before returning a `no solution found` error, `bal` is the limit for balance and `collat` the same for Collateral. You can change those as you please.

Let me know if you don't get any part of it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, many thanks. I'll now try to adjust it myself and use it for a larger dataset. Many thanks, Tim

Comment: Works also perfect on a large dataset and more constraints. Perfect

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. I am really glad I could help :)

Comment: You are welcome:) Would it also be possible to make the number of loans dynamic? We are now looking for a certain number of loans, but this is not what we per se need. For example, we want to indicate that the number of loans has to be between 50 and 100. Next step would be that we don't indicate the number of loans (rows), but just the minimum sum of balances. We want for example minimum 200 million worth of loans, no matter how many loans. (We of course use the restrictions like collateral/size).

Comment: You can definitely do it using the method from the above example. I cannot post an answer here at the comments but you can always post it as a new question, well explained as here, and then I can probably help later on. If I were you though I would try to do it using the above method. You will learn a lot if you try it out on your own and I am sure people (including myself) will be glad to help if you have any questions :)