# Sample in R with unknown sample size

Tags: r, while-loop, conditional-statements, sample

This question relates to my question at [Subset data with dynamic conditions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244579/subset-data-with-dynamic-conditions-in-r)
The idea is to create a random sample from a dataframe where certain conditions must be met.

The size parameter indicates the number of rows that the sample should contain. But we actually don't care how many rows are in, as long as the conditions are met. So in the example below we have the size set at "3" whereas it would work with 2 as well.

Is there a way of not indicating the number of rows? It seems that  `sample()` needs to have a sample size... I guess I can set ranges (1:8) for example to the size parameter. But once I simple set (1:8), sample uses 1.

```
dataset <- data.frame(balance=c(25000,50000,35000,40000,65000,10000,5000,2000,2500,5000),
                      rating=c(2.11,4.49,2.45,1.94,2,4.2,10,8,6,7.45)
                      ,id=c(1:10))

pick_records <- function(df,size,bal,rating, max.it) {
  i <- 1
  j <- 1
  while ( i == 1 ) {
    s_index <- sample(1:nrow(df),size)
    print(s_index)
    output <- df[s_index,]
    out_num <- lapply(output,as.numeric)

    if (sum(out_num$balance) > bal &
          mean(out_num$rating) <= rating      
    ) {
      return(output)
      break
    }
    print(j)
    j <- j + 1
    if ( j == max.it+1) {
      print('No solution found')
      break}     
  }
} 

#set parameters: #loans, total balance,max mean rating, #iterations
loans=2;balance=70000; rating=3;iterations=5000
pool <- pick_records(dataset,loans,balance,rating,iterations)
```

Comment: Perhaps, you might want to use `sample` inside the "size" argument? `replicate(10, sample(1:10, sample(1:8, 1)))`