# Optimizing dataset based on several conditions

Tags: r, subset, solver, optimization

I am trying to construct a (optimal) subset from a large dataset based on several conditions. I know that there are some possibilities to construct such a subset. See for example: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244579/subset-data-with-dynamic-conditions-in-r). I tried this function but it is unsatisfactory since it takes to long to find such a subset and might be not "intelligent" enough. Below you can find some sample data

```
data <- data.table(id=rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f"),3),
               balance=c(1000,2000,1500,2000,4000,1500,
                         800,2000,1300,1800,2000,500,
                         700,1900,1100,1600,500,30),
               rate=c(1100,1500,1000,700,300,200,
                      400,700,500,1300,1600,700,
                      800,1100,1200,700,400,150),
               grade=c(70,100,90,50,150,40,
                       30,80,55,80,85,20,
                       35,70,55,75,15,10),
               date= rep(c(2012,2013,2014),each=6))

data_agg <- aggregate(cbind(rate, grade) ~ date, data = data.frame(data),sum,na.rm=T)
data_agg$ratio <- data_agg$rate / data_agg$grade

> data_agg$ratio    
[1]  9.60000 14.85714 16.73077
```

Now the objective is (e.g.) to minimize the increase in the data_agg$ratio over the years and at the same time include at least 3 id's in this subset.

By looking at the data we see e.g. dat ID == "e" has a ratio of 300/150=2 in 2012, 1600/85=19 in 2013 and 400/15=27 in 2014. The objective of my answer is to minimze the increase over the years, thus deleting "e" might have a desisarable effect on the subset.

```
datasubset <-subset(data, subset = id!=c("e"))

data_aggsubset <- aggregate(cbind(rate, grade) ~ date, data = data.frame(datasubset),sum,na.rm=T)
data_aggsubset$ratio <- data_aggsubset$rate / data_aggsubset$grade

data_aggsubset$ratio
[1] 12.85714 13.58491 16.12245
```

And indeed, the ratio is more stable over the years now. Thus my question is whether there is some optimizer function which seeks IDs such that this ratio is e.g. within a bandwidth of +/- 50% of the starting value (9.6 in this example) and contains at least three IDs. My original dataset is large, thus I am looking for a more intelligent function than the one I attached in the link. Please let me know if anything is unclear. Thank you in advance!

Comment: "intelligent" how?  faster?  sure... write a better algorithm, which is I think what you're asking for here.  I would figure out what the most generalized form of your question is and ask that.  *If* you get an answer then you can get help implementing it.  You might find out that there is no 'intelligent' way to go about it.